# Application called twice during a long running process while invoking a bat file from mvc

Tags: python, c#, asp.net-mvc, batch-file, iis

I am trying to call a batch file from c# mvc to compare some files using python. used process.start and the next line goes process.waitforexit().
The call executes fine but when the process runs for more than 5 mins a new folder(output folder created while comparing files) is created.If the process runs within 5 mins then its fine.if it takes more than 5 minutes, a new application-beginrequest and application start_event is triggered.. is started and every 5 minutes i can see the even triggered. Is there any change I have to in IIS  if the process takes long time to run?

Comment: The IIS is probably and older machine with a lot of users which is probably why it is taking longer than you expect.

Comment: Is this behavior recorded in the event viewer? I think the application pool recycling may cause this problem. After the application has been running for more than 5 minutes, the application pool considers that there is no operation, so the old process is recycled to create a new process, and the new process calls the batch file again.

Comment: No this is not recorded  in event viewer..Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: Without exact logs or error messages, it is difficult to determine what caused the problem. At present, what I can think of is the process re-invocation caused by application pool recycling.